# Is it possible to setup logback configuration programmatically?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, syslog

I am new to logback, I want configure logback programmatically. Currently I am using static configuration like below:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="KIWI" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>localhost:8080</syslogHost>
        <facility>LOCAL0</facility>
        <suffixPattern>%thread: %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</suffixPattern>
    </appender>
    
    <logger name="com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbacksyslogexample.message.kiwi" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="KIWI" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Is it possible to set the syslogHost dynamically?

Comment: You might be looking for http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/Configurator.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If you have any sample code to use the above, that will be very helpful.

Comment: I've never used it. The only reason I know it exists is because [this documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) mentions it, though I couldn't find good examples (but maybe I missed something). If you read the Javadoc of `Configurator`, `LoggerContext`, and `Logger` (and possibly some other interfaces/classes) you should be able to work out what to do. For example, you add an appender to a logger with `Logger#addAppender(Appender)`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible to configure logback programmatically, you need to extend ContextAwareBase and implement Configurator, like code below

```
public class MyLogbackConfigurer extends ContextAwareBase implements Configurator {
    @Override
    public void configure(LoggerContext lc) {
        addInfo("Setting up default configuration.");

        ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> ca = new ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        ca.setContext(lc);
        ca.setName("console");
        LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> encoder = new LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent>();
        encoder.setContext(lc);


        // same as
        // PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
        // layout.setPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n");
        TTLLLayout layout = new TTLLLayout();

        layout.setContext(lc);
        layout.start();
        encoder.setLayout(layout);

        ca.setEncoder(encoder);
        ca.start();

        FileAppender f=new FileAppender();
        f.setEncoder(encoder);
        f.setLayout(layout);
        f.setContext(lc);
        f.setFile("log.log");
        f.setAppend(true);
        f.setName("logFile");
        f.start();

        Logger rootLogger = lc.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        rootLogger.addAppender(ca);
        rootLogger.addAppender(f);


        Logger springLogger = lc.getLogger("org.springframework");
        springLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN);

    }
}
```

and you will need to create a file under **src/main/resources/META-INF/services/ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator** which will have the class name of your configurer. Here is my [example](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/blob/master/logback-code-config/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator) and for the [config](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/blob/master/logback-code-config/src/main/java/com/mascix/demo/MyLogbackConfigurer.java).

I did not use SyslogAppender before but you can change the example I gave and you can use **System.getProperty("proName")** or **System.getenv("envName")**

Before start implementing everything from scratch, have you tried to change xml like below ?

```
 <syslogHost>${SYSLOG}</syslogHost>
```

And run the jar like this "java -jar yourjarpath.jar -DSYSLOG=localhost:8080" this way you will not need to write that configure class [detailed doc](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution).

Comment: First answer that actually works. Been looking for five hours. Thank you! +1